# Excel Macro Recorder: When the filename is always changing

Tags: excel, vba, object

I currently use a lot of spreadsheets to do my job that visualize incoming data that is always changing.

The main issue that I have run into is the file that I export every day has a naming system that is based on some algorithm that has relation to the date and time that the information was pulled, but is somewhat generated at random. This means that the workbook always has a different name and because of the copious amounts of reports that we pull, I prefer to be able to extract the information, transfer it to the main sheet, and delete the exported file. The macro that I came up with through recording my actions works fine if ALL other Microsoft applications are closed (if Word, Outlook, or another Excel file are open, the macro crashes with a define error).

Can anyone suggest a solution for being able to execute a code to format a file when the name is constantly changing?  I can paste an example of what I have, but it's a long code due to the formatting.  The basics are:

```
Sub RECORDTHIS()
Dim sht As Object

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

sht.Select
sht.Name = "MYDATA"

'Lots of formatting commands

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give us an idea of the naming convention? I assume from your post you want to be able to determine the name simply from some date parameters?

Comment: I have tried to decipher the naming system, but as it is a system where multiple offices can access reports daily, there is no way for me to keep track of the sequence that it will be in at any given time. The date is a constantly changing factor, as is the number of reports pulled.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you "Open" the workbook you want to process. Something like this

```
Sub DemoOpen()
    Dim FName As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")
    If FName <> False Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FName)
        Dim sht As Worksheet
        Set sht = wb.ActiveSheet
        sht.Name = "MYDATA"
        'Lots of formatting commands
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a possibility...however, as the files export to a temporary folder that is not easily found (the more steps it takes, the less likely anyone else is to use the macro) I am pretty sure that my coworkers will just give up and not try further.  Is there a way for the macro to get the current name of the open file each time?